# Generating combinations follow by each element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, combinations

I have a list of chars `chrs = ['A','B','C','D']`. How can I generate the outputs like this `['A','AB','ABC','ABCD','B','BC','BCD','C','CD','D']` in python?

Thank you so much!

Comment: did your output miss `D`? it should be `['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'B', 'BC', 'BCD', 'C', 'CD', 'D']`

Comment: Something doesnt adds up with the desired output, what exactly is the task you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
s = ''.join(chrs)
res = [s[i: j+1] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(i, len(s))]
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'B', 'BC', 'BCD', 'C', 'CD', 'D']
```

Answer (score 2):

A one liner is to use function [powerset()](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.powerset) from package [more_itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/).

Like the following:

```
from more_itertools import powerset
l = ['A','B','C','D']
list(powerset(l))
# [(), ('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'D'), ('A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')]
```

Then you can join it to strings, and sort to get the desired output.

```
ll = ["".join(x) for x in list(powerset(l))]
sorted(ll)
# ['', 'A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'ABD', 'AC', 'ACD', 'AD', 'B', 'BC', 'BCD', 'BD', 'C', 'CD', 'D']
```

You can also easily get read from the empty string by `ll[1:]`

Comment: If you have `itertools` and not `more_itertools`, you can find a two-lines definition of `powerset` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html    `def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))`

Comment: @Stef this is the way to evolve basically. If you dive deeper into the `itertools` library you will reach an implementation that doesn't include any built-in complex functionality. Moreover, that I gave this solution as an alternative to what @Aviv Yaniv suggested

Answer (score 1):

```
chrs = ['A','B','C','D']
all_combinations = []
for current_start_index in range(len(chrs)):
    for current_combinations_lengh in range(current_start_index, len(chrs)):
        all_combinations.append(''.join(list(chrs[current_start_index:current_combinations_lengh+1])))

# Sort, if neccesary
# all_combinations.sort()

# ['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'B', 'BC', 'BCD', 'C', 'CD', 'D']
print(all_combinations)
```

Comment: What I need of the output is `['A','AB','ABC','ABCD','B','BC','BCD','C','CD']`. Your answer is quite different with the output that I want. Your output is: `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD', 'ABC', 'ABD', 'ACD', 'BCD', 'ABCD']`

Comment: @JustinBình Edited

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution without using any package or module and with basic idea:

```
    chrs=['a','b','c','d']
    chrs=''.join(chrs)
    a2=[]
    i=0
    j=1
    while(i<len(a) and j<len(a)):
        a2.append(a[i:j+1])
        j+=1
        if j>=len(a):
            i+=1
            j+=i
    a2.append(chrs[-1])
    print(a2)
```